# Calendric vs Calendrical

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, dialects, ic-ical

When choosing an adjective to refer to the nature of a calendar system, such as how we have months of varying length, is it more appropriate to use *calendric* or *calendrical*?  Is there any difference, perhaps in context?  Or is it a British vs American English thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED has only one entry for both words: there is no difference between them other than the one being a syllable longer than the other.

Laconic lovers of brevity who try never to use an *-ical* word when the corresponding *-ic* one will do would surely select the lighter *calendric*.

On the other hand, prolix writers and stentorian speakers of a more long-winded bent take precisely the opposite position — and, conflating length of discourse with quality, choose therefore the gratuitously heavier and more ponderous *calendrical*.

The choice is yours.